# Double click not work in chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I try doing chrome extension which double click cell in table. I write function which find cell by text value and then i connect find element with double click Here is my code:

content_script.js

```
function searchAndClickCategory(category)
{
var tdTags = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var searchText = category;
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < tdTags.length; i++) {
  if (tdTags[i].textContent == searchText) {
   found = tdTags[i];
    break;
  }
}

var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('dblclick', true, true);
found.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

}

searchAndClickCategory("Text in cell table");
```

manifest.json

```
{  
    "manifest_version": 2,  

    "name": "Such Activity",  
    "description": "Wow",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],  

    "browser_action": {  
        "default_icon": "icon.png",  
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>activity</title></head>  
<body>  
    <button id="clickactivity">click</button>  
    <script src="popup.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
}

document.getElementById('clickactivity').addEventListener('click', injectTheScri
```

pt);

But double click doesn't work. And i didn't have any erors in chrome console.